# What's the best way to do "application settings" in Android?

Tags: android

I'd like to store some application settings (like the URL of an API, and some settings for testing) for an Android application.

I mostly work as a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) developer, so I'm used to using the file `app.config` for this purpose. What's a good way to do it in Android?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Many applications may provide a way to capture user preferences on the settings of a specific application or an activity. For supporting this, Android provides a simple set of APIs.

Preferences are typically name value pairs. They can be stored as “Shared Preferences” across various activities in an application (note currently it cannot be shared across processes). Or it can be something that needs to be stored specific to an activity.

1. Shared Preferences: The shared preferences can be used by all the components (activities, services etc) off the applications.
2. Activity handled preferences: These preferences can only be used with in the activity and can not be used by other components of the application.

**Shared Preferences:**

The shared preferences are managed with the help of `getSharedPreferences` method of the `Context` class. The preferences are stored in a default file(1) or you can specify a file name(2) to be used to refer to the preferences.

(1) Here is how you get the instance when you specify the file name

```
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";
   SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

`MODE_PRIVATE` is the operating mode for the preferences. It is the default mode and means the created file will be accessed by only the calling application.  Other two mode supported are `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` and `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`. In `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` other application can read the created file but can not modify it. In case of `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` other applications also have write permissions for the created file.

(2) **The recommended way** is to use by the default mode, without specifying the file name

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Finally, once you have the preferences instance, here is how you can **retrieve the stored values** from the preferences:

```
 int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);
```

To **store values** in the preference file `SharedPreference.Editor` object has to be used. `Editor` is the nested interface of the `SharedPreference` class.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
editor.commit();
```

Editor also support methods like `remove()` and `clear()` to delete the preference value from the file.

**Activity Preferences:**

The shared preferences can be used by other application components. But if you do not need to share the preferences with other components and want to have activities private preferences. You can do that with the help of `getPreferences()` method of the activity. The `getPreference` method uses the `getSharedPreferences()` method with the name of the activity class for the preference file name.

Following is the code to get preferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);
```

The code to store values is also same as in case of shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreference(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
editor.commit();
```

You can also use other methods like storing the activity state in database. Note Android  also contains a package called `android.preference`. The package defines classes to implement application preferences UI.

To see some more examples check Android's [Data Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) post on developers site.

Comment: thanks. Looks like what I need to do is to use an XML file for what I'm after (or maybe I use the XML as the data to intially load), but the preference stuff is useful for another part of my project.

Comment: You can use the xml file for init. You need to call something like `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.profiles_preferences, false);`

Comment: Wonderful answer. Please note, that the class is PreferenceManager not Preference(s)Manager.

Comment: This guide could be useful too: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Comment: +1. Just one tiny bit to keep in mind. After setting the value in `preferences` object, calling `editor.apply()` is recommended over `editor.commit()` as the former will handle the saving in background.

Comment: I am bit confused here. The sharedPreferences is for storing user settings over the app, not apps settings. The user (and me also) was wondering where to store app settings , ex API url or other settings that the app use to work properly.

Comment: @albanx , I store API url in a CONSTANTS interface something like ,
public BASE_API_URL = "http://....."

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/UdiOshi85/GenericSettings for fast implementation