# Single Sign On for Android Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

Friends,
      I need to know much about Single Sign On support for Facebook. I have two applications on my device and I have to post the feed. I login the very first time from either one of the applications, but I need it to continue using the same login credential and session for the other application without showing the login page. Is this possible in android? If so please guide me how to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure both apps reference the same Facebook app `client_id` and `client_secret`.  Once the user authorizes one of your Android apps, store their `access_token`, and share it between both apps.

Comment: One thing to note is that the `access_token` only lasts for a few hours unless you request the `offline_access` extended permission, which makes it last forever (or until the user changes their mind and revokes permission).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps see

[Preserving login session across multiple Android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316120/preserving-login-session-across-multiple-android-apps)

and then

[Write a private access file to another app's files directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318729/write-a-private-access-file-to-another-apps-files-directory)

My solution is to write the login information (I guess `access_token`) to a file on both apps and make each app check it's file and the other app's file modification time. the one modified most recent wins.

You would have to write up some code for that..